# Comparing MANY date/time objects in Python

Tags: python, csv, datetime, comparison

I have a .csv file with the format:

```
Username, Datetime
user1, datetime1
user1, datetime2
user2, datetime3
user2, datetime4
user2, datetime5
user3, datetime6
user1, datetime7
user2, datetime8
```

The file can sometimes be very large (sometimes up to 300,000+ users). I want to compare datetime objects to see if one specific user has datetime objects that are within X days of each other.

What would be an efficient way to execute this task? Obviously, I don't want to compare datetime objects of different users, so would it be wise to create some data structure first, like a dictionary?

I was thinking it might be sufficient to create a dictionary of the form:

```
{user1: [datetime1, datetime2, datetime7], 
user2: [datetime3, datetime4, datetime5, datetime8], ... }
```

then iterate over each combination of datetimes for each user? Is there a faster, more efficent way to make this comparison?

Comment: Is this list sorted? If yes, you can try to implement binary search algorithm.

Comment: `datetime` is more expensive than a simple integer timestamp. Is the original file already sorted by time? You may only need to keep part of the dataset. if you have memory constraints, you could do two passes, where the first pass creates per user files and the second pass processes the files. That could be done with `multiprocessing` to spread out the work. If this csv is updated periodically, you can keep the existing per user files, remember where you left off, and only update the new stuff.

Comment: You could try to use `numpy` and `numpy.loadtxt` as well. In general, numpy is extremely fast when it comes to files and comparing (well it's used by astronomers).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dictionary would mean storing all 300k+ records in memory at once, which may not be what you want.

If the csv file is sorted, first by user and then by timestamp, you would only have to read and process one line at a time, which seems pretty efficient.